# Initialize object with excel file contents and save to database

Tags: arrays, excel, postgresql, object, ruby-on-rails-4

I feel like I'm taking crazy pills, but I've just hit a brick wall and can't hack at this anymore. The answer seems simple, but my mind is numb and I can't break through this particular wall.

I am using the Roo gem to import an excel doc (xls format) and push it into an array. I wind up with an array of arrays. Easy enough, that works fine.

So then I try and take the values of that array and assign them to an object's attributes. The trick seems to be iterating over the rows, assigning the array value to the proper object attribute, saving, and then moving on the next row. I'm sure what I'm doing is all kinds of garbage, but I'm stuck and can't think of a solution.

Here is my controller:

```
class PlanesController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @plane = Plane.new
    @plane.upload
  end
end
```

This is my model:

```
    require 'roo'

    class Plane < ActiveRecord::Base
        attr_accessor :id, :name, :version

    def upload
            arr = []
            sheet1 = Roo::Spreadsheet.open('lib/assets/test.xls')
            sheet1.each { |hash| arr<<hash}

            i = 0
            while i < arr.length do
                @id = arr[i][0].to_int
                @name = arr[i][1]
                @version = arr[i][2]
                i += 1
            end
        end
    end
```

Basically is how do I get my values stored in the 'arr' array to be assigned to my object? I want @id to wind up being Plane.id, which is accessed in my controller by the instance variable @plane. I feel like I'm doing this wrong, because I'm essentially trying to create multiple objects based on however long the spreadsheet is and saving each new row to populate my database. Like I said, probably super-garbage, but I'm missing something basic and appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just changed my controller's new action to include `@person = Plane.create(plane_params)`, then put the `plane_params` in a module which I included in my controller...was able to use the newer Rails 4 strong params, and also import the .xls file, all in that single method (instead of my model, which in retrospect doesn't make much sense if I'm using `.create`). Works like a charm now, but has me wondering if there's a gem/3rd party plugin for this laying around that I missed.